# Symfony2 Assetic wrong cssrewrite resources path in css/less files

Tags: css, symfony, less, twig, assetic

The cssrewrite filter produces wrong urls after the rewrite:
i have my bundle which contains one .less file located in 
**Resources/public/less/common.less**

I also have one image,located in **Resources/public/images/colorfulbg.jpg**

i run from the command line :

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

which produces in the web directory the correct public structure:

```
web
+--bundles
   +--mybundle
      +--less
      |  +--common.less
      |
      +--images
         +--colorfulbg.jpg
```

in my template i have the following:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/mybundle/less/*' filter='cssrewrite,less' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

That folder just contains one .less file , which is simply:

```
@bg: #f4f4f4;
body 
{
  background-image: @bg url(../images/colorfulbg.jpg);
}
```

There is something wrong, since the rewrited background path is:

```
url(../../bundles/mybundle/images/colorfulbg.jpg);
```

and therefore the background is not applied

What am i doing wrong?

I am using symfony 2.3 and assetic bundle 2.3
Thank you

Comment: i don't think i understand what do you mean...

Comment: What happens if you simply use `background-image: @bg url(images/colorfulbg.jpg);`?

Comment: the url is rewritten from:
url(../../bundles/timerbase/images/colorfulbg.jpg);
to
url(../../bundles/timerbase/less/images/colorfulbg.jpg);
i would expect something like (../images/colorfulbg.jpg)

Comment: Well, that's that then. ;-) Personally I had my share with SASS on assetic and the conclusion was that you just don't want to do that. Hope you have more luck!

Comment: so, what is the solution?

Comment: i frankly have no idea. i started using gulp & node assets composition

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when specifying `write_to` option for assetic (suppose, I wanted my styles output into `web/assets/css/styles.css`):

```
assetic:
    write_to:       '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/assets'

    assets:
        my_stylesheets:
            output: 'css/styles.css'
            inputs:
                - 'bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css'
```

I could not find a better solution rather then not specifying anything else than `web/` folder for `write_to` option (or not specifying it at all). However, you can still use subfolders for every separate asset:

```
assetic:
    write_to:       '%kernel.root_dir%/../web'

    assets:
        my_stylesheets:
            output: 'assets/css/styles.css'
            inputs:
                - 'bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css'
```

P.S. In both of upper cases styles will be in `web/assets/css/styles.css`, but in first case `csrewrite` will give incorrect paths, while the second one will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your using the wrong type of definitions to your assets in your template, see the following ( note the @ prefix ). Also in your css you have to go relatively down from your Bundle/Resources/public/less folder. So it's not `/bundles/` or `../bundles` **but** *most likely* `../images/`.

```
    {% stylesheets filter='less,cssembed,?yui_css' output='css/final.css'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/beautifulslider.css'
        '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/less/site.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

**Update1**

Given the above, one of my projects is in the same kind of setup, it's just still on 2.2 but i don't think that would matter, I just gave it a try removing these lines from my .less

```
    & > a {
    background:transparent url('../images/btn-big-gray.png') repeat-x;
    }
```

Images gone after

```
    xxx michael [master] $ app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

I restore the line and after kicking assetic again they're back... I think the dis recommendation doesn't count for the fact LESS is involved?

Comment: nope ... the cookbook itself suggests not to doing so, because of cssrewrite : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets

btw the problem is that the url INSIDE the css/less file is incorrect. the css/less file is correctly included

Answer (score -3):

This is a common problem, I suggest you to not use cssrewrite filter and use urls with `/` at the beginning

```
url("/bundles/mybundle/images/colorfulbg.jpg");
```

Of course this approach has a drawback that website must be installed in a root directory for domain but to be honest I haven't seen Symfony project installed in sub directory.

Comment: even after removing cssrewrite and using the url as you suggested it doesnt'work :/ i think app_dev.php gets in the way ...

Comment: @Stormsson do your OS support symlinks? Windows doesn't. try again to ```php app/console assets:install web --symlink``` then navigate to web directory and check if path is correct

Comment: Yes it does,i'm on osx. the paths seems all correct, i confirm that the structure i posted in the first post has been checked